# Scapy: Layer derived from Packet with own init

Tags: python, constructor, initialization, scapy

is it possible to construct an own layer with it's own `__init__()` function?
The way I'm trying to do it is:

```
>>> class SomePacket(Packet):
...     def __init__(self, number):
...             fields_desc = [IntField("Number",number)]
... 
>>> packet = SomePacket(1)
>>> ls(packet)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 1213, in ls
    if not isinstance(obj.payload, NoPayload):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 180, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: payload
```

Whats's wrong about doing it like that and how should I write the class in order to use it with a kind of constructor?

Comment: You are attempting to build your own layer in Scapy?

Comment: Yes, I wanted the layer to have the values which i give to the constructor. I know that I can just assign all the values by accessing the attributes like `packet.number=X` but I wanted to do all that when creating the layer in one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sky is the limit, you can extend or misuse scapy the way you like. Therefore, yes it is possible to have your own `__init__` but you'll have to re-implement some scapy code or at least call the superclass to fit the interfaces. Also you'll have to define `fields_desc` as a class/instance var instead of a `__init__` local var (i.e. change your code to `self.fields_desc` to make it an instance var or make it a class var explicitly).

But, if you're just trying to assign values to your layer fields it'd be better to not reinvent the wheel and use scapy how it was designed as it already provides that `__init__` like interface.

```
class SomePacket(Packet):
    fields_desc = [IntField("Number",1),  # capital letters are not convenient
                   IntField("yournumber",1),]


packet = SomePacket(Number=1, yournumber=99)
packet.show()
```

resulting in:

```
###[ SomePacket ]###
  Number    = 1
  yournumber= 99
```

The only layer where I ever had to override the `__init__` was an SSL/TLS layer that provided a hidden field for the ssl context (crypto/keys) spanning multiple layers (for decryption, ...)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I think you're right. I actually really don't need write an own `__init__`.